# How to see my network packets

Tags: gratis, network-monitor, windows-xp

I'm learning SSL protocol to secure a local website. In order to better understand the effects of my modifications, I'm looking for a tool which allow me to see my live network traffic.

**Requirements:**

- Admin right not needed
- Ability of listening localhost trafic
- Gratis
- Works on XP and 7
- Can capture HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, FTPS packets

Answer (score 2):

[WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) would be the best tool for you in this case.

It's been a while since i've used it, so I can't say off the top of my head, but with a quick lookup of it, i know it can handle all of those.

- [Admin access is not required](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Security#Administrator.2Froot_account_not_required.21)
- [Localhost Access](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)
- [Gratis](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)
- It's listed OS' for windows are XP and up
- It supports filters for HTTP, HTTPS, [FTP](http://wiki.wireshark.org/FTP), and FTPS

It also supports a very nice [wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/) for it, as well as a [Q/A](https://ask.wireshark.org/) section, so you can always look up features I haven't mentioned...

Comment: Wireshark for Windows needs **[RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap)** to listen on 127.0.0.1, and RawCap seems to need admin right (I get an socket authorization exception) :/